Include all chapters, but compile only one?
Instead of one big tex file, I put the chapters into separate tex files for faster compilation. My main tex file now looks like this:
\include{ch-abstract}
\include{ch-acknowledgments}
\include{ch-introduction}

Assume I compiled everything once, then I only changed something in ch-introduction. Is it possible to compile only ch-introduction but display all other unchanged files in the PDF?
Note that \includeonly{ch-introduction} is not a solution, as this only displays the introduction in the PDF.

no you need to use includeonly for drafting and then do a complete run at th eend to make a full document, pdf has all kinds of global structures and byte offsets that make it hard to combine them (you could combine separate pdf at the end using pdftools or the pdfpages package, but typically you lose links and other annotations)

You could follow the subfiles-route to compile individual files without the rest; later you still can compile everything in your main-document. See here for the manual https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles , and here for examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfiles

Can you please add (i.e. via EDIT) to your question, why you want to do it, or think it's useful or neccessary? Thank you
